# Prove or disprove A complement is independent to A

Tags: probability

Prove or disprove: For an event $A$, if $P(A)\neq1$ and $P(A)\neq0$, then $A$ and $A^c$ are independent.

I did something like this:

Say that

$P(A\cap A^c)
=P(A)P(A^c)
=P(A)(1-P(A))
=P(A)-(P(A))^2
>0$

Hence when its $>0$, it is always independent

Did I do it correctly?

Comment: How could they be independent?  If $A$ occurs, then $A^c$ does not, and conversely.  Indeed, despite your claim, $A\cap A^c=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, independence means that the knowledge on one event gives no information on the other event. In this case is obviously false. About your calculation: in fact, supposing independence you can deduce a contradiction, namely:
$$0 = P(\emptyset) = P(A\cap A^c) = P(A)P(A^c) = P(A)(1-P(A)) \ne 0.$$